# Making a prediction after training and fitting a RNN Sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, text-classification

I am trying to get predictions from my sentiment analysis models that classify 500 worded News articles. The models validation loss and training loss is in are about the same and their scores are relatively high. However when I try to make predictions with them I get the same classification result in all of them regardless of the text input. 
I believe that the problem might be on the way I am trying to make a prediction (I pad my string with spaced characters). I was hoping that someone here could shed some light on this issue (my code below). Thank you for your help

```
comment = 'SAMPLE TEXT STRING'
for i in range(300-len(comment.split(' '))):
    apad += ' A'
comment = comment + apad
tok.fit_on_texts([comment])
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([comment])
X = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X)
yhat = b.predict_classes(X)
print(yhat)
prediction = b.predict(X, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)
print(prediction)
```

The output of this script is below. Both prediction and predicted classes, are regardless of the text input always 0 for some reason:

[[0]] [[0.00645966]]

Comment: Are you fitting token "again"? That's a problem. Your tokens must be constant.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for getting back to me so quickly. Could you elaborate a bit more on your answer? How can I use pass a string to my model without fitting the tokens? When I do I get an error.

Comment: You must use the same tokes you used when training. You must fit your tokens only once before training and keep them.

Comment: Thank you so much you were right! please make it an official response so I can mark your response as the one that answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the tokenizer.

You can't `fit` the tokenizer again, because you will have different tokens for each word. You should fit the tokenizer only once before training and then save the tokens to be used with all new text.